# Foods/drugs/vitamins to avoid, or not avoid, for tardive dyskinesia

Tags: neurology

I'm half expecting this to be closed as off-topic as seeking personal medical advice, but I'm going to try not to phrase it that way and see how it flies. For full disclosure, I was recently diagnosed with tardive dyskinesia (the doctor actually said it's almost purely tardive dystonia with no dyskinesia, but I read that tardive dystonia is considered a form of tardive dyskinesia) and have been taking austedo.

I'm aware there was a study done on taking vitamin E ([Soares‐Weiser, et al. 2011](https://espace.library.uq.edu.au/view/UQ:249760/UQ249760_OA.pdf)) and it seemed to be inconclusive. From what I understand, there was no improvement, but there did seem to be a slowing of the deterioration. Is there anything known on foods/vitamins/drugs to avoid, or not avoid, in a similar vein to this study?

### References

Soares‐Weiser, K., Maayan, N., & McGrath, J. (2011). Vitamin E for neuroleptic‐induced tardive dyskinesia. *Cochrane Database of Systematic Reviews*, (2). doi: [10.1002/14651858.CD000209.pub2](https://doi.org/10.1002/14651858.CD000209.pub2) pmid: [11687073](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11687073)

Comment: Asking questions to understand your illness is okay as long as you don't ask for a diagnosis or treatment advice, so I don't think you're going to get this question closed for that reason. But we do require prior research here, and you mentioned a particular study. What would be good would  be if you found a link to that study and added it to your question.

Comment: @Carey Thanks, I added a link.

Comment: You may want to investigate B6, (Pyridoxine). " The Merck Manual reports toxicity effects at 2000 mg/day and suggest a safe level of 200 mg/day for chronic use." "The Institute of Medicine has established an upper tolerable limit of 100 mg/day for adults for vitamin B6 (pyridoxine). ". You would probably need at least 200mg. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3046018/#!po=0.568182

Comment: This study may have used the P5P form of B6. I did not read the entire study. Lerner, V. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/m/pubmed/18052557/ So you can investigate this if you want and discuss with your doctor before adding any supplement.

Comment: (Your doctor can do a risk/benefit analysis and decide whether a higher dose of the Vitamin is warranted, then he/she will follow your case).